# Prove $\forall (m,n)\in \mathbb{N}^{2}: m<n\implies m-n\notin \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was trying my hardest to prove this before defining $\mathbb{Z}$ but I couldn't. It was not an assignment or anything, just math for fun. May anyone provide a proof?

**Remark** Assume order in $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as follows $\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb{N}^{2}: a<b\implies \exists c\in \mathbb{N};\ c\ne 0\ (a+c=b)$

Comment: Do you know that for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $m \leq m+n$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yeah, I proved it!

Comment: Then note $m = n + (m-n)$

Comment: @Lambert That's the definition of $(m-n)$.

Comment: The issue is maybe that at this point you haven't defined $m - n$ yet (for $m < n$), so the statement doesn't mean anything yet. Of course, once you have defined ${\mathbb Z}$ and have defined $m - n$ (as an element of ${\mathbb Z}$), you can prove that $m - n \not\in {\mathbb N}$. So, instead, you can now prove that there is no element that 'could play the role of $m - n$', i.e., $\not \exists c \in {\mathbb N}: m = n + c$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag On your  advice I proved $\forall (a,c)\in \mathbb{N}^{2}: c<a\implies \sim \exists b\in \mathbb{N}: a+b=c$

Answer (score 1):

Let, if possible

(m-n ) is in N.

Since, m<n & both are natural numbers then there exists a natural no K such that n=m+k .

Now,
m-(m+k) =m-m-k =-K

if K is a natural no then -K is a negative integer.
So, -K is in N.

Hence, we got a contradiction .

So, our assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I’m proving it under the assumptions that the followings are true:
 $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$. and
$(-b+b)=0$.

 Also, by definition $\forall m,n\in\Bbb N. m\ge n \text{ if}\ m=n+a. \text{Where } a\in\Bbb N. $

Proof.
You can prove by contradiction.
Assume $m-n\in \Bbb N$. Then $\exists a\in \Bbb N: a=m-n$.
Then $a+n=(m-n)+n=m+(-n+n)=m+0=m.$
$\implies m\ge n$.  A contradiction.